# Condition for determining day or night when using datetime module in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, conditional-statements

I want to seperate a dataset into two subsets.
I used the datetime module of python to achieve the task and while using boolean mask I got an error.
I am greeted with the error - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.

I want to seperate a dataset into two subsets. One is of the nighttime and the other is of the daytime and I have decided the criteia as follows

```
7:00 A.M. to 7:00 P.M. as daytime and 7:00 P.M. to 7:00 A.M. as nighttime.
```

When trying to implement this by using boolean masks as follows

```
nighttime = traffic[(traffic['date_time'].dt.hour >= 19)  or (traffic['date_time'].dt.hour < 7)]
```

Can someone guide me towards the correct condition and why my condition does not work.
My code until now can be found here (https://github.com/Vivek1325/Heavy-Traffic-Indicators-on-I-94/blob/main/traffic%20analysis.ipynb)

Comment: you can use the `|` operator for the or condition; `traffic[(traffic['date_time'].dt.hour >= 19)  | (traffic['date_time'].dt.hour < 7)]`

Comment: In which case is logical or failing and why are we using the bitwise or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the data_time column formatting you linked (e.g `2012-10-02 09:00:00`), I would first create a column just with the `hour`:

```
df['hour'] = df['date_time'].str.split(' ').str[1].str.split(':').str[0].astype(int)
```

And then separate the dataframe into two dataframes with your condition:

```
nighttime = df[(df['hour'] >= 19) | (df['hour'] <= 7)]
```